# Bundle ID not listed in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

Let's say my app bundle ID from Xcode is `com.myname.TodayNews`
So I'm trying to add a new App in iTunesConnect but i can't find my Bundle ID `com.myname.TodayNews` from the list !

[image: see here]

and when I tried to register a new bundle ID same the one on my Xcode `com.myname.TodayNews` on the [Developer Portal](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifiers/bundle/bundleCreate.action)

I got an error !

[image]

Any one can explain how to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like you've either found a *critical* issue with iTC - provided nobody else has a `com.myname` exactly like you or else you've already submitted things and (maybe) wasn't case-sensitive? (That last thing I don't know.) Honestly, that sounds like a solid reason to contact Apple - you (used to?) get two support calls a year. EDIT: I really do wish Apple provided a search mechanism better than iTC. One last option - App Store **name** doesn't *have* to be anything like the AppID. Final thought - we're not talking about a new IAP for an app, right?

Comment: The bundle ID is unique and have make sure that it did not match any thing else or Xcode will complain, and we're not talking about a new IAP for an app

Comment: And again, it's *possible* that (a) someone else copied the `com.myname` part before but until now there is no conflict, (b) you already reserved the `com.myname.unique` ID, or (c) you found a *critical* issue. For me? I use `com.companyname.app` and further add a *fourth* qualifier for any IAP. Seriously, you have two choices - file a bug report or create a new AppID. Nothing says that a unique app "A" from company "B" needs to have an app called `com.b.a` - it can be `xxx.z.q` for all Apple cares. (At least I believe.) It just needs to be unique.

Comment: Last note. I **always** create the App ID in developer.apple.com first and *then* in the Xcode project. Don't think it completely matters... you can get unique IDs, app names, you name it at any point in the development of an app.

Comment: @desperado_ah have you checked my answer & got solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Well here are possible solutions for the issue :

> - First try to sign on from developer account & iTunes. Than try to re login & see if you get it listed now
> - Another option is You can wait & try it later on after few minutes or hour it should work automatically. Its because there could be
>     internal issues of apple site as they always doing silent maintenance
>     work on their site
> - Last & ver effective solution is you can contact support team & tell them what issue you are facing so they will immediately take
>     action on it & will get it resolved for you

Hope it will help you.